# How to get multiple aggregation in a dataframe? cumsum and count columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need a column which aggregates using the `count()` function and another field using the `cumsum()` function in a dataframe

I would like to group it only once and the `cumsum` should be grouped with `Site` almost just like the count. How can I do this?

```
#I get the count by grouping site and arrived  
df_arrived_gby = df.groupby(['Site','Arrived']).size().reset_index(name='Count_X')

#I do the cumsum but it should be groupby Site and Arrived same as above
#How can I do this?
df_arrived_gby['Cumsum_X'] = df_arrived_gby['Count_X'].cumsum()
print(df_arrived_gby)
```

Data example (it is not grouped by Site, so it continues adding the others):

```
      Site  Arrived      Count   Cumsum
198    T  30/06/2020      146     22368
199    T  31/05/2020       76     22444
200    V  05/01/2020       77     22521
201    V  05/02/2020       57     22578
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it using groupby on a new dataframe column as shown below:

```
df_arrived_gby['Cumsum'] = df_arrived_gby.groupby(['Site'])['Count X'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum())
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the values from the Count_X column, then you can cumsum():

```
df_arrived_gby['Cumsum_X'] = df_arrived_gby.Count_X.values.cumsum()
```

Let me know if that helps

Comment: about the groupby, if you grouped before, you dont need to do it again, it should be grouped already

Comment: It did not cumsum by site and arrived. I did groupby once for doing the counting